# How do I tell flutter that just inputting SPACE should be considered null in my flutter texting app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a basic texting app on flutter. At the moment just hitting the spacebar n times and hitting send would result in a text bubble with n spaces. How do I tell flutter that just spaces should be considered null or should not be sent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you should [`trim`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/String/trim.html) the `String` that you're going to send with the `trim` method. Trimming removes whitespace that usually isn't needed, just like in this case. Input formatters are not necessary and may prevent users from typing. Wherever you're getting your text input and sending it, add in this trimming.

```dart
String toSendString = inputText.trim(); //Send toSendString instead of inputText
```

You may only want to trim a certain side of the `String` instead, which can be done with `trimLeft` or `trimRight`.

Then, if the string is empty `toSendString.isEmpty`, don't send the message.

---

Alternatively, if trimming every message is for some reason undesirable, you can just check if all of the characters are spaces and conditionally send the message based on that with something like the following:

```dart
bool isAllSpaces(String input) {
  String output = input.replaceAll(' ', '');
  return output == '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide what are you using for the input. So if you are using
Textfield for input you can use Regex Expression in the input so now one cannot start a sentence with a space this is a work around but will stop user to enter blank spaces all the way and should impose at least one letter required.

```
 TextField(
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    
                                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9-_\\s]+$')),
                               ] ),
```

Add the inputFormatters property in your textfield. There also may be better solution than this but this will definitely restrict user to not send all blank message

Comment: This doesn't work but you've introduced me to inputFormatters. I'll try to dive deep into it. Thanks! Please let me know if you have a solution..

Comment: @graywartzdoomski I have edited the REGEX sorry it was a mistake before. Please try the current one again

Comment: Thanks for your help @krishbhanushali I'm sure this works but I've gotten a more apt solution which I've implemented.